# Redux.js , Webpack.js , index.html - my redux render function doesn't update the index.html DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, webpack

I'm working currently on webpack. For a reason that I don't understand, my redux functions doesn't upload the DOM. 
However, the Google console returns the good results of my functions.

Everything seems good, but there is something in the code that create this bugg : my DOM don't render the li of my redux render function.

So, I have check the Webpack config and the index.html data flow, everything seems great. What I have missing if any ?

here my webpack.config.js :

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");
module.exports= {
  mode: "development",
    entry : "./src/index.js",
    output: {
      path : path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
       publicPath: 'dist',
        filename : "main.js"
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ],
    //Loaders   tell    webpack what    to  do  with    the entry   file
    module:{
        rules: [{
            test: /.(js|jsx)$/,
            loader: "babel-loader",
            exclude : /node_modules/
        }]

    },
    devServer :{
      publicPath: "/",
      contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
      hot: true
    }
}
```

here my index.js :

```
import {
  createPost,
  editPost,
  setFilter
} from './actions';
import {
  appReducer
} from "./reducers.js";
import {
  createStore
} from "redux";

let store = createStore(appReducer)
const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => {
  console.log("state: ", store.getState())
})
store.dispatch(createPost("Brian", "Hello world =D !"));

const root = document.getElementById('root');
const render = () => {
root.innerHTML = ''
const { posts } = store.getState()
posts.forEach((post, index) => {
const item = document.createElement('li')
item.addEventListener('click', () =>
store.dispatch(editPost(index, post.text + '!'))
)
const text = document.createTextNode(post.user + ' - ' + post.text)
item.appendChild(text)
root.appendChild(item)

})
  const stopRender = store.subscribe(render)
}


store.dispatch(createPost("user1", "text1"))
store.dispatch(createPost("user2", "text2"))
```

here my reducer.js :

```
import {
  CREATE_POST,
  EDIT_POST,
  SET_FILTER
} from "./actionTypes";
import {combineReducers} from "redux";
export function postsReducer(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {

    case CREATE_POST:
      {
        const {
          type,
          ...post
        } = action

        return [...state, post]
      }

    case EDIT_POST:
      {
        const {
          type,
          id,
          ...newPost
        } = action
        return state.map((oldPost, index) =>
          action.id === index ? { ...oldPost,
            ...newPost
          } : oldPost)

      }

    default:
      return state
  }


}

export function filterReducer(state = "all", action) {
  if (action.type === SET_FILTER) {
    return action.filter
  } else {
    return state
  }

}

export const appReducer = combineReducers({
post : postsReducer,
filter : filterReducer
})
```

here my index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE   html>
<html>
        <head>
                <meta   charset="utf-8">
                <title>Learning Redux</title>

        </head>
        <body>
                <div id="root"></div>
                <script src="main.js"></script>

        </body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: can you paste your reducer as well ?

Comment: Hi Pranay, it's done

Comment: Are you still facing the issue ?